# Changing microsoft azure Identity issuer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have two microsoft azure accounts one of which contains all of the users & groups.
I am really struggling to figure out how to move all of the users and groups to a different azure account so that the issuer name is changed to my custom domain name.

I want to migrate all users & groups to a different account that is under my custom domain name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration may not be possible between tenants with different domains but we can create bulk users from one tenant to the other tenant we want to add  by following steps.

- **I created two tenants with domain  ##myOrg1@onmicrosoft.com and ##myOrg2@onmicrosoft.com**

[image]

- **In my org1 tenant i have users named  user1 and user2**

[image]

- **In my org2 tenant I have user named myOrg2user**

[image]

- **Go to create bulk users in new tenant i.e; Org2 to get the users template.**

[image: Bulk create]

- **Download the template.**

[image]

- **You will get a template something like this , There remove column 3 which is just an example row.**

[image: org2 csv template]

- **Now go to Org1 tenant and get all users to be migrated to org2
  tenant.**

[image]

- **You will get all users in csv template something like below:**

[image: org 1 csv users]

- Copy the UPN (USER PRINCIPAL NAME) and Display name and other
  required fields from org1 users  you want to add from the org1 tenant
  (downloaded users)  and And paste here  in upn and display name
  fields of csv template downloaded from org2 and give some random
  password (valid).
- Here you need to change the UPN in the domain name part which you
  needed for new tenant(Org2). Here you need to give the custom domain
  name of new tenant(Org2 ) i.e myOrg2.onmicrosoft.com.
- Don't forget the version .

[image: Copy upn and display name]

> **NOTE**:Please make sure to communicate to the users the change in the
> domain name  UPN for new tenant or mail all users the change.

- Now you can go to AAD portal and submit this users csv in new tenant.

[image]

- Now if you refresh the page ,you can see the users added with
  identity issuer having the new domain (present tenant).

[image: output]

**Reference:**
[Migrate users between tenants -Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/15661/migrate-users-between-aad-directoriestenants.html)

Comment: Thankyou So much i have worked it all out thanks to you apprecite it alot.